# Cannot compile robotjs for electron on my mips platform Linux

Tags: linux, electron, mips, robotjs

I am trying to use robotjs in my electron on a mips based Ubuntu. Since electron has mips linux version only up to version 1.8.8 (after that, no support), so I download this 1.8.8 electron-mips version. Then, I need to install Node, by checking the node version inside electron 1.8.8, I found it is node8.2.1, so I download this version source code and compile it in my mips platform, seems OK, and node and npm can run successfully. After this, I install libxtst-dev libpng++-dev, and then download the source code from robotjs homepage and unzip it in my directory, and under this directory, "npm install nan".

Then, I follow the robotjs homepage and try to compile it for my platform with command like:

```
node-gyp rebuild --runtime=electron --target=1.8.8 --disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --abi=57
```

During compiling, it always reports error(robotjs.cc, line 159): `no matching function for call to v8::String::Utf8Value bstr(...)`.
And the same error occurs for line 447 and 486.

I checked the line 159/447/486 in robotjs.cc, they are as follows:

```
159:    v8::String::Utf8Value bstr(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), Nan::To<v8::String>(info[0]).ToLocalChecked());

447:    v8::String::Utf8Value fstr(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), Nan::To<v8::String>(value).ToLocalChecked());

486:    v8::String::Utf8Value kstr(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), Nan::To<v8::String>(info[0]).ToLocalChecked());*
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with this, how should I do? thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The current version of robotjs will not support anything earlier than 10.16.0

You'll need to go back to this commit and (I may have went a couple of commits too far) to get this to work. https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/commit/b26c7ee0e3dd05420370350e540c48ae9d38f06c

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I have compiled robotjs for electron in x86 Windows and Linux with node 10.11.0 and they worked very well just about 1-2 months ago, with src code downloaded from robotjs homepage. but it does not work for node8.2.1 now.